# Understanding eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Here is a definition, that I find difficult to grasp:

Let $A$ be an n-by-n matrix, so that it corresponds to a transformation $R^n \rightarrow R^n$. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for A, then there is a vector $v\in R^n$, such that $Av =λv$. Rearranging this equation shows that $(A - \lambda \cdot I)v = 0$, where $I$ denotes the n-by-n identity matrix. This implies the null space of the matrix $A-\lambda \cdot I$ is nonzero, so $A-\lambda \cdot I$ has determinant zero.

First, do we multiply vector $v$ with identity matrix solely to simplify the computations? What does it mean that the null space of the matrix $A-\lambda\cdot I$ is nonzero? Where is it implied? Why determinant of $A-\lambda \cdot I$ is nonzero?

Comment: The string of equalities $Av = \lambda A = \lambda v$ does not make sense. The middle equality is not true (that's a matrix, the other two are vectors). The equality is simply $Av = \lambda v$.

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvalue equation is $Av = \lambda v$, moving $\lambda v$ to the other side, we have $Av - \lambda v = 0$. We view $Av - \lambda v = 0$ as $(A-\lambda I)v = 0$ because, technically speaking, the object $A-\lambda$ does not make sense. (However in more advanced mathematics, $I$ is typically suppressed and understood to be lurking there.)

The nullspace of $A-\lambda I$ being nonzero means exactly that there exists a nonzero vector $v$ such that $(A-\lambda I)v = 0$. This is a simple restatement of the eigenvalue equation.

For any square matrix $B$, the existence of nonzero $w$ such that $Bw = 0$ implies that $\det(B) = 0$, so it is also true for the matrix $B = A-\lambda I$. This is also true in the other direction: if $\det(B) = 0$, then there exists nonzero $w$ such that $Bw = 0$. This statement is not as trivial as the previous and takes a little bit of work, depending on what you know about determinants. I suggest you look over your notes regarding invertibility of a matrix. There are something like $10$ major equivalences involving determinants, nullspace, row space, column space, and other things.

Answer (score 1):

We multiply $v$ by $I$ out of necessity. Imagine if we didn't: then we would end up with the equation:

$$(A - \lambda)v = 0$$

which is nonsense! In what world would you subtract a *scalar* from a *matrix*?

So after following the computations:

$$Av = \lambda v \Rightarrow Av - \lambda v = 0 \Rightarrow (A - \lambda I)v = 0$$

we wish to find all nonzero $\lambda$ and $v$ so that $Av = \lambda v$ by using the right-hand identity. But notice that this is a homogenous linear equation, so if $A - \lambda I$ were nonsingular, the only satisfactory $v$ would be $0$. Thus to find the nonzero $\lambda$, it has to be the case that $A - \lambda I$ is singular. This occurs exactly when $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$, which is just a polynomial in $\lambda$ that we can solve.